# ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required while reading from file

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I'm trying to read a dictionary off a file and then make the string into a dictionary. I have this,

```
with open("../resources/enemyStats.txt", "r") as stats:
        for line in stats:
            if self.kind in line:
                line  = line.replace(self.kind + " ", "")
                line = dict(line)
                return line
```

and the line in the txt file is,

```
slime {'hp':5,'speed':1}
```

I'd like to be able to return a dict so that I can easily access the hp and other values for the enemy character.

Comment: You might be better off using json or pickle to store your dict

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dict()` does not parse Python dictionary literal syntax; it won't take a string and interpret its contents. It can only take another dictionary or a sequence of key-value pairs, your line doesn't match those criteria.

You'll need to use the [`ast.literal_eval()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) instead here:

```
from ast import literal_eval

if line.startswith(self.kind):
    line = line[len(self.kind) + 1:]
    return literal_eval(line)
```

I've also adjusted the detection of `self.kind` a little; I'm assuming you wanted to match it if `self.kind` is found at the start of the line.

Answer (score 0):

For other people running into this thread: in Python 3 the `json` package does the trick here translating a string into a dictionary:

```
dict('{"ID":"sdfdsfdsf"}')
# ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

import json 
type(json.loads('{"ID":"sdfdsfdsf"}'))
# dict
```