# ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required?

Tags: python, data-structures

I am trying to time my word concordance program with my BinarySearchTree inorder to see the execution time it takes. But I am getting the above error.

```
def concordance():
    wordConcordanceDict = BinarySearchTree()
    with open('stop_words.txt') as sw:
        words = (line.strip() for line in sw)
        stop_words = set(words)
    with open('WarAndPeace.txt') as f:    
        for line_number, line in enumerate(f, 1):
            words = (re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',word).lower() for word in line.split())
            good_words = (word for word in words if word not in stop_words)
            for word in good_words:
                # it doesn't work as defaultdict. So we have to check
                # if key is present in dictionary or not
                try:
                    # key is present
                    wordConcordanceDict[word].append(line_number)
                except:
                    # key is not present, so we create a new key
                    wordConcordanceDict[word] = [line_number]
    # the given implementation of dictionary don't have a method to get all keys/ items as there in python dictionaries.
    # instead, there's a function to get all key, value pairs as a string
    # we call that method and convert it to a dictionary
    wordConcordanceDict = re.sub(r', ',',',wordConcordanceDict.__str__()).split()[1:-1]
    wordConcordanceDict = dict(x.split(":") for x in wordConcordanceDict)    # getting error here


# import regex
import re
from binary_search_tree import BinarySearchTree
# import time module
import time
# start time
start = time.time()
# given function call
concordance()
# end time
end = time.time()
# display time taken
print(end - start)
```

I do not know what the error means and how to solve it. Please let me know.

Comment: [Here is an answer that may helps you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30843678/7594682) also can you provide the error traceback?

Comment: @SidaliSmaili thanks for the reference. Now I got the issue but still I am confused how to integrate that in my code. Please if you have time to review my code and suggest me the changes.

Comment: I wasn't able to re-execute the code, if you provide more details maybe I could help

Comment: @SidaliSmaili                                                                                                     
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Lenovo/Downloads/Project7/Project 7/project7/New Part B Correct one.py", line 38, in <module>
    concordance()
  File "C:/Users/Lenovo/Downloads/Project7/Project 7/project7/New Part B Correct one.py", line 23, in concordance
    wordConcordanceDict = dict(x.split(":") for x in wordConcordanceDict)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Comment: @SidaliSmaili yeah the code contains module that should be imported and I haven't provided that. How can I provide the supporting modules ?

Comment: yes it would be more helpful to provide the modules, you can put hem in a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) and provide the link

Comment: @SidaliSmaili https://pastebin.com/seN28ZGn

Comment: You are giving wrong parameters to the python dict() fonction, it take parameters as dict(key=value) while the x.split(:) return a list.
You should change that line in order to provide the right format of parameters
wordConcordanceDict = dict(x.split(":")[0]=x.split(":")[1] for x in wordConcordanceDict)
should solve the error.

Comment: @SidaliSmaili its giving syntax error now. I think there is some mistake error

Comment: try separating the statement: 
for x in worldCincirdanceDict:
key=x.split(':')[0]
value=key=x.split(':')[1]
worldConcordanceDict2[key]=value

Comment: @SidaliSmaili Trackback: IndexError: list index out of range. Please, run the code yourself. This way you can better understand the problem.

Comment: @SidaliSmaili hey please help me out.

Comment: The whole code is pretty complicated but the error is clear you are misusing the dic() fonction, your x variable does not contain ':' so when you do split() it return a single value, when it should return a (key,value)

Comment: @SidaliSmaili yeah I am also confused now what is happening :(